# How to find textbox id near to checkbox in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, textbox

I have dynamically generated a datatable using jquery of which first column is checkbox and last column is textbox. My requirement is, when user will uncheck the checkbox then textbox value should be cleared. I have tried to do with closest function, but it is not happening.
Below is my code:

```
$('#statement-table').dataTable({
         "data": json,
         "dom": 't',
         "info": false,
         "pageLength": 8,
         "columns": [
             {"data":""},
             {"data": "statementCode"},
             {"data": "dueDate"},
             {"data": "statementBalance"},
             {"data": ""}

         ],
         "columnDefs": [
             {className: "pad-md-left-p-10 pad-top-bottom-p-10 white-active-bg mouse-link", "targets": [0,1,2,3,4]},
             {
                 'targets':   0,
                  'render': function(data, type, full, meta) {
                      ++index;
                          return '<input type="checkbox" id="select-checkbox'+index+'" name="payment-checkbox" id="select-checkbox"/>';
                  }
             },
              {
                 'targets': 4,
                 'render': function (data, type, full, meta){
                     return '<span class="dollar-font">$</span>'+
                     '<input type="number" id="payement-textbox'+index+'" name="payment-textbox" min="1" max="100000" maxlength="9" class="payment" placeholder="--" value=""/>';
                 }
              }

         ],
         "aaSorting": [[2, 'desc']],

     }); //End of datatable function
```

jQuery Code is as below:

```
$("input[name=payment-checkbox]").on('change', function() {
             var ischecked = this.checked;
                if (!ischecked) {
                    $(this).closest(".payment").val('');
                }

            });
```

When I uncheck the checkbox, then change event get triggered but it does not empty textbox. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to traverse up to `tr` element, that's what [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) does. Then [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) the descendant `payment` element.

```
$("input[name=payment-checkbox]").on('change', function() {
    var ischecked = this.checked;
    if (!ischecked) {
        $(this).closest('tr').find(".payment").val('');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> `$("input[name=payment-checkbox]").on('change', function() {
>                var ischecked = this.checked;
>                   if (!ischecked) {
>                      $(this).parent('tr').siblings().children(".payment").val('');
>                   }
>               });`

You can use:
$(this).parent('tr').siblings().children(".payment").val(''); Or
$(this).parent('tr').siblings().find(".payment").val('')